# Dataset of hardware benchmarks

Tags: data-request, computing

I want to buy a new computer, but I am limited in money, so I need to decide which components to chose in order to maximise performance. I want to make this choice in most scientific way, so I need some open dataset which will tell how component affect performance. I know, that price depends on performance non-linearly, so I need dataset to determine optimal investing.